# Lumen + Eloquent 6.X join and aggregate into JSON structure

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, lumen

Considreing two tables `lectors`, `lessons` and their Eloquent models `Lector` and `Lesson`.
`Lectors` table content:

```
| id | name | 
| 1  | John |
| 2  | Jack |
```

`Lessons` table content:

```
| id | state | lector_id |
| 1  | new   | 1         |
| 2  | new   | 1         |
| 3  | old   | 1         |
| 4  | new   | 2         |
```

I would like to query the database to get the cout of new lessons and cout of old lessons for each lector.
Example DB output is

```
| id | name | count_new | count_old |
| 1  | John | 2         | 1         |
| 2  | Jack | 1         | 0         |
```

I'm not particulary concerened about the query at this stage. I would like my API to return a JSON result like below. That is the thing I'm struggling to do with Lumen/Eloquent.

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John",
    "count_new": 2,
    "count_old": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Jack",
    "count_new": 1,
    "count_old": 0
  }
]
```

I'm interested in general approach to avoid querying tables separately and then looping over stuff in the code as I saw all over the internet. That seems wrong. Is it possible to do that with API's available in Eloquent? Didn't find much help in the docs. The closest I got was with `subJoin`s.

Comment: Did you look at https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models?

Comment: Did you try anything? Show your work.

Comment: @miken32 I did try subJoins, which work until I add second aggregate .. then it multiplies the number of result in the json array. plain joins create a flat structure where lector repeats. This is a simple case to present general problem. I also have more complex queries, where I would like to add client array to each lector along with the aggregates

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I spent last month reading the docs back and forth and yet missed this part! It looks promissing, I will give it a go, thank you!

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir thank you very much! It works perfectly ... resulting query is not the best  Icould imagine, but it is one query only and the code is very nice. Please post your comment as an answer and I will accept it

Comment: I think it would be more helpful if you post your query as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models

```
$result = Lector::withCount([
            'lessons as lessonsnew_count' => function (Builder $query) {
                $query->where('state', '=', 'new');
            },
            'lessons as lessons_old_count' => function (Builder $query) {
                $query->where('state', '=', 'old');
            }])->get();
```